# BizAgi Tables and m-m relationships

Tags: bizagi

BizAgi tables are used to view collections in 1-m relationships.

It is also possible to view m-m relationships from the point of view of one entity (thus, a 1-m relationship).

The add and delete buttons don't work with m-m relationships and no errors appear.

Has anybody used them successfully?

Answer (score 0):

My interpretation with an example:

One contract has N clients, and one client has N different contracts. You want to use collections to represent this connection.

The only was I see of representing this information is to have a table of contracts, to which the edit/detail form shows a table of clients for that contract.

You might also want to consider using a form link as a column of that table.

Let me know if this is a correct interpretation.